# Magento product Image re-sizing when selecting a product option

Tags: product, image

I've got that bug, when i selected a product option on the right, like size, color or anthing, my product image, which is a square, is reduced by 25% or something like this

It's still in the center, still the same proportion, but the image is smaller then the div. 
How and where can i fix this ?

my website (online) http://www.cosplay-heaven.com/index.php/cosplay/cosplay-assassins-creed1.html
If you wanna have a try, just click on the link, and select a size for the cosplay and you'll see

Thanks a lot

Comment: :) so what you expect from us?

Comment: It seams you have a plugin that changes the main image when you select an option.  Original image `http://www.cosplay-heaven.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/i/file_673_6__46220_zoom_9.jpg`, after selecting size `S` the image becomes `http://www.cosplay-heaven.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/375x460/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/i/file_673_6__46220_zoom_9.jpg`. It seams you are not using the color swatches from 1.9 so you should contact the person that developed the image changing feature.

Comment: On your `<img id="image"...>`, you have some Javascript resizing the image when you change sizes. Look for any references to `id` `image` in your scripts.

Comment: And no we did took a module to take off the zoom of the image thats why